# Fastest path to Lua SHA256 RFC-2104 compliant HMAC signature?

Tags: c, lua, amazon-web-services, sha256

I'm running Debian Linux, and for a Lua script I need to create a SHA256 checksum to authenticate requests to Amazon Web Services.  They don't say for sure but it looks as if they may want a base64 encoding of the resulting SHA256 checksum.

- I'd be happy if someone had done a Lua binding.
- I'd be content if someone could help me figure out how to use the command-line `/usr/bin/sha256sum` for this purpose.
- I'd settle for a pointer to C code and deal with the hassle of the binding and the base64 encoding myself.

I surely don't need to reimplement SHA256 for myself; if someone has an implementation in ANSI standard C that they like, please let me know.  Or a better solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about LuaCrypto, a front-end for OpenSSL:

http://luacrypto.luaforge.net/

Comment: Perfect!  Where were you Saturday? :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like mushclient has already written a [Lua wrapper](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#MxIwlh-BGwQ/mushclient/lua_compress.c&q=lualib_api%20sha256) for a SHA-256 library.

Comment: Unfortunately this only does a SHA256 digest, not the HMAC signing I'm looking for.  I wound up writing the binding myself from somebody's reference implementation.  But +1 for the pointer to mushclient, because it's good for us all to know about.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around might be the free signing service at [http://apisigning.com/](http://apisigning.com)